# How can I provide shared hosting on my Windows 2008 r2 box?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, asp.net, .net

I have set up Windows 2008 R2 and added the web server role, IIS and MS SQL Server 2008.

How do I provide hosting space and cpu cycles and ram to clients.

I would like to provide them with all versions of the `.Net Framework`, `ASP.NET` and `ASP.NET MVC`.

Comment: Frankly, having to ask this kind of question demonstrates that you are not experienced enough to offer any kind of hosting to clients in a reliable way. If you face problems that affect your clients (and possibly their businesses), you might have no way to quickly act and fix  them. Running a server is a complicated topic and doing so for customers (with a habit to break things) is even more involved and no task for a beginning admin.

Comment: do doubt i believe you are correct in part of that but please be advised that i intent to study this process much before i start providing hosting and charging for it. if nobody does have enough words for how i approach this process thats ok i will be happy if links and directions are offered

Comment: How about 1 year experience of system administration where you have to do everything yourself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to use a server control panel that is tailored to multi-tenancy and web hosting.  There is no native way that Windows can perform this. It's not an easy task or something that can be done on your own without heavy investments in time, development and money.

There are a few open-source tools that offer this kind of functionality, however most of the ones that are reliable appear to be commercial or have a commercial component to a base open-source utility. Some examples:

- [Parallels Plesk](http://www.parallels.com/products/plesk/)
- [Webmin](http://webmin.com/)
- [Enkompass](http://www.cpanel.net/windows/overview.html)
- [Hosting Controller](http://hostingcontroller.com/)
- [Website Panel](http://www.websitepanel.net/)
- [zpanel](http://www.zpanelcp.com/)

I've worked to cull all known server / web hosting control panels into a single blog post at my blog. Consider researching some of them on your own: [Definitive List of Web-Based Server Control Panels](http://thenubbyadmin.com/2011/12/06/definitive-list-of-web-based-server-control-panels/)

Comment: You are going to blow Wesley o.O?

Comment: It's the least he could do

Answer (score 0):

As it sounds like you're a little unsure I suggest you install Plesk. Better yet, instead seek a managed hosting provider who can help you as you learn what to do. It's not fair to clients to put them on your server if you don't know what you're doing!

Comment: ok if i have installed plex will that expose everything i need to offer for people to connect to my server and manage their websites? what about managing their domains?

Comment: I would definitely advise you purchase a reseller hosting plan instead. Or if you want to learn to be able to administer a server yourself, please get a managed server.